# Javascript camel case split for json result

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

In javascript json column names, I want to Split camel case string for example `CustomerID => Customer ID`

Below code working but splitting as `Customer I D`

```
 var title = field.replace(/([a-zA-Z][a-z]*)/g, " $1");
```

I don't want to split abbreviated words or consecutive Caps, how can I achieve this.

Also I want to make first letter uppercase if it is a small letter.

Comment: CustomerID is capital case, not camel case. Camel case would be customerId.

Comment: abbreviated assume as consecutive capital letters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a function into the replace() and call toUpperCase

```
"custID".replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g,"$1 $2").replace(/^([a-z])/, function(a){ return a.toUpperCase();});
```

Comment: I'd consider using `[:lower:]` and `[:upper:]` instead of `a-z` and `A-Z`. Otherwise, good answer, +1.

Comment: @ineffablep This solution is not good for each case :: http://jsfiddle.net/wAJes/

Comment: Just need to swap the replace order, not a big deal. http://jsfiddle.net/wAJes/1/

Comment: @SQB well if the answer is JavaScript than it does not apply.

Comment: But compare to my solution you still do slower job :: http://jsfiddle.net/wAJes/2/

Comment: Have you heard of [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/)? Better interface for testing performance.

Comment: @epascarello \*Looks up\* Oops, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

```
= field.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + field.replace(/([a-z])(?=[A-Z])/g, "$1 ").slice(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var title = field
              .replace(/([a-z]+)([A-Z]+)/g, "$1 $2")  // "aaAA" => "aa AA"
              .replace(/([A-Z]+)([a-z]+)/g, "$1 $2") // "AAaa" => "AA aa"
              .replace(/^([a-z])/g, function(x, y) { return y.toUpperCase(); }); // caps first char
```

If `field` is `"aaaAAAbbDDD"`, the above will return `"Aaa AAA bb DDD"`

Comment: how can I make first letter of a to A

Comment: +1 But you don't need the `+` quantifiers in the first two expressions.

Comment: @techfoobar I'd leave out the second replace, as this would split `CustomerID` into `C ustomer ID`. The only thing you want to do, is insert a space if you go from lowercase to uppercase.